# Get value from meta box

Tags: metabox

I'm trying to write a plugin that adds a value from a meta box to a post on save_post. But I can't figure out how to get the value from the form field in the meta box This is the relevant code:

```
function sw_add_document_meta_boxes() {
    if (get_current_screen()->id == 'dokument') {
        add_meta_box('access_level', 'Tilgangsnivå', 'sw_ac_meta_box');
    }
}

function sw_ac_meta_box() {
    $html = '<p class="description">';
    $html .= 'Velg laveste tilgangsnivå';
    $html .= '</p>';
    $html .= '<select name="access_level" id="access_level">';
    $html .= '<option value="4">Ansatt</option>';
    $html .= '<option value="3">Fagansvarlig</option>';
    $html .= '<option value="2">Daglig leder</option>';
    $html .= '<option value="1">Superbruker</option>';
    $html .= '</select>';
    echo $html;
}

function sw_ac_set_access_level($id) {
    $meta_value = 
    add_post_meta($id, 'access_level', $meta_value, true);
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'sw_add_document_meta_boxes');
add_action('save_post', 'sw_ac_set_access_level');
```

I guess my question is, what should I write on the line '$meta_value =' in the 'sw_ac_set_access_level()' function? Take into account that I'm a total wordpress noob, so I might be on the wrong track entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If form `<select>` is part of the form element that get submitted, then you should check the `$_POST['access_level']`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
function sw_ac_set_access_level($id) {
    $meta_value = $_POST["access_level"]; // name of select
    update_post_meta($id, 'access_level', $meta_value );
}
```

You can get mor detail here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Answer (score 0):

You should validate $_POST['access_level'] first to save its value

You can try this

```
function sw_ac_set_access_level($id) {
  if(isset($_POST['access_level']) && !empty($_POST['access_level'])){
    update_post_meta($id, 'access_level', $_POST['access_level'] );
  }   
}
```